# Fix binding error for a binding applied in a style

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am getting a binding error in my output panel when I run my application:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Shapes.Ellipse', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=Width; DataItem=null; target element is 'TranslateTransform' (HashCode=59715965); target property is 'X' (type 'Double')

I am trying to create a style that would apply a TranslateTransform on all the ellipses in a Canvas. The binding works, but when I start my application, I get the error in my Output panel. How can I fix this error?

**EDIT: The binding does work, I just want to get rid of the error in the Visual Studio Output window.**

If I move the RenderTransform from the style into the `Ellipse` tag, the error goes away, but I want this transform to be used from within a style because it needs to get applied to many ellipses.

This is the XAML I am using:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Ellipse">
            <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <TranslateTransform>
                        <TranslateTransform.X>
                            <Binding 
                                    RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Ellipse}}"
                                    Path="Width"/>
                        </TranslateTransform.X>
                    </TranslateTransform>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Canvas>
        <Ellipse Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Red" />
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

Comment: This code works for me. In both cases: Window.Resources and Ellipse.Resources

VS2013

Comment: I'm also using VS2013, and the code does work, but I get the strange error inside the output window. Is your output window empty when you run the code?

Comment: I have only red transformed ellipse inside the Window.

Comment: I don't really understand what this code is trying to achieve. You have a style that is binding the `TranslateTransform.X` to it's parent `Ellipse`? Why do you need a binding? Why not just use `{TemplateBinding Width}`?

Comment: @MikeEason Yes, I want to bind the `TranslateTransform.X` to its parent `Ellipse`. I can't use `TemplateBinding` because I'm not using a template, I'm using a style. Can I use something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is an issue in WPF, but one that Microsoft won't fix.

More info here:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1423399/system-windows-data-error-4-when-using-relativesource-findancestor-inside-a-translatetransform-inside-a-style